# Add cart without reloading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried adding a cart in my application, but how you can while in order to add a new cart page does not reload, but the cart increases.

my controllers

```
function add_cart($code) {
    $produk = $this->Model->get_id($code);
    $data = array(
                    'id' => $produk->code
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'name' =>  $produk->name        );

    $this->cart->insert($data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_id($code) {
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('mytable')
                      ->where('code', $code)
                      ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    } 
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($product as $row) ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-item">
               <div class="info">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="price col-md-12">
                           <h5> <?php echo $row->name_product ;?></h5>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="separator clear-left">
                       <p class="btn-add">
                           class="hidden-sm" href="<?php echo site_url('home/add_cart/'.$row->code);?>">Add</a></p>
                   </div>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to replace the href to request the add_chart operation, and get the response to refresh the page content without reload the page.

Comment: thanks @kris Roofe, but What command if the value is met to refresh the page?

Comment: use javascript to refresh the dom